# Directed graph implementation in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

I'm taking a class on data structures in java right now and we are to figure out how to implement a digraph class.
Just off the top, I thought that having a Linked List kind class with a value field and an array of link (self referential) fields like the code below:

```
    public class Digraph<T>
    {
        T vertex;
        Digraph<T>[] edge;

        public Digraph(T val, int maxDegree)
        {
            vertex = val;
            edge = new Digraph<T>[maxDegree];
        }
    }
```

After I wrote this out, I realized that this isn't a little to no mess method of approaching this prompt.
How can I implement a digraph that isn't as messy as my code bit up there? Or is this an okay approach?

Comment: It doesn't look messy to me, but this type of questions belong here to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: First think about what you will use this data structure for.  Then make a list of the operations that it will have to support to satisfy its purpose.  Then design a data structure that supports efficient implementation of those operations.

Answer (score 2):

I think using your linked-list way to implement a graph is not a good ieda. **Unlike linked list and tree, Graph is not a recursion structure in nature.**

I will implement it based on the fact that **a graph is consisted of a list of Vertexs, and each Vertex is connected to its neighbours by Edges**:

```
class Graph<E> {
    public List<Vertex<E>> vertexs; 
}

class Vertex<E> {
    public E val;
    public List<Edge<E>> connections; 
}

class Edge<E> {
    public Vertex<E> source;
    public Vertex<E> destination;
}
```

But the simplest way to represent a graph is to use an [Adjacency_matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)